# WooCommerce not saving add_fee when order is placed

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make it so when I select from a dropdown box at checkout, a fee will be added.
I have the ajax request which returns the information with the fee calculated in, which also updates the current checkout page. But once I place the order, the fee is gone. What is the correct way to add in the fee after an ajax request?

My ajax request:

```
var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_update_order_review',
            security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
            add_order_fee: '55.00',
            post_data: $( 'form.checkout' ).serialize()
        };

        $.ajax({
                type:       'POST',
                url:        wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data:       data,
                success:    function( response ) {
                        if ( response ) {

                    var order_output = $(response);
                    $( '#order_review' ).html( $.trim( response ) );
                    $('body').trigger('updated_checkout');
                    console.log(response)
                            }

                },
                error: function(code){
                    console.log('ERROR');
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
```

and my plugin function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );

function woo_add_cart_fee(){
global $woocommerce;
    if(isset($_POST['add_order_fee']))
    {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Same Day Shipping', '55.00', true, 'standard' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar code running in one of my plugins that adds fees on Checkout. Your code seems to execute fine. I removed the $_POST['add_order_fee'] condition & it added the charges on the checkout page as well as on the page where the order is placed.

I noticed one thing:

```
$('body').trigger('updated_checkout');
```

I am using in my plugin:

```
jQuery("body").trigger("update_checkout");
```

Notice the 'update_checkout' v/s 'updated_checkout' in your code. Perhaps that could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a similar problem.
When you send first ajax, system will add fee and second ajax by call "update_checkout" fee will not add because didn't have $_POST.
so my solution is add WC fees to a sessions and add it when "update_checkout" called. This is code that I am using in my plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', array($this,'calFee') );
public function calFee() {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION[ $this->id . '_cart_fees' ] ) ) {
        WC()->cart->fees = $_SESSION[ $this->id . '_cart_fees' ];
    }
}
```

Please notice you must enable session_start.

```
add_action('init', array($this,'register_my_session'));
function register_my_session()
    {
        if( !session_id() )
        {
            session_start();
        }
    }
```